# how to embed youtube video in virtumart 2.0 product description page

Tags: joomla2.5

i want to embed youtube video into virtumart2.0 product description page, but i am unable to embed the youtube video. i have searched about it and come to know that if in array $tagBlacklist have to remove embed and object tag from blacklist.
I have done with this, but my problem is remaining same, youtube video is not embeded with my product description page.For this i have also used AllVideos (by JoomlaWorks) module,but it works only in articles not in virtumart product description.

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can [see here](http://www.encros.fr/catalogue-encros/kit-toner-couleur/kit-toner-couleur/kit-recharge-toner-4-couleurs-brother-dcp-9045cdn/6976-37986) , i have embed you tube video in product detail page.

you should install Easy Embed Video Plugin in joomla.

after just put {youtube}CEDiiDYIHw8{/youtube} in your description.

you can Download Plugin [Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/video-channels/15752)

Comment: i tried to use this plugin but it does not fullfill my condition..:(